# Elegant parsing of percentages - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've inherited a database that has tax rates stored as strings. They come in the following flavors:

- Number: `0` or `7`.
- Decimal: `6.5`.
- Null: `null` (should be interpreted as zero)
- String: `6.5%`.
- This Thing: `6,5%` or `6,5`

I need a sleek way to generate a decimal mid-sql statement:

`SELECT tax_rate FROM table`

Using some conjunction of MySQL functions, I'd like to convert the tax_rate in all formats to a decimal.

- `6.5%` becomes `.065`
- `null` becomes `0`
- `6,5` becomes `.065`

Any recommendations?

---

To be clear, I *could* go through and sanitize the data, but I have no control over the software that generated these entries and future entries **will** be created using the formats discussed above. This would necessitate sanitizing the data repeatedly. I'd rather just handle it on my end via clever (or convoluted, I suppose) SQL statements.

Comment: Sometimes, when I'm having a bad day at the office, I like to remind myself that at least I haven't got this mess to sort out.

Comment: Hahaha, you have earned yourself some kudos :P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple way . . . sort of:

```
select coalesce((replace(taxrate, ',', '.') + 0) / 100, 0)
```

This covers the examples in your question.

This is using implicit conversion of the string.  That converts all leading digits (and decimal places) to a number.  The `+ 0` is not strictly necessary, but that is the convention that I use for implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it will fit the bill! Haven't had a moment to try it, but will let you know :)